# How to cd and execute an executable in ubuntu through java program

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

Hello and excuse me for being new to java coding, but what I am trying to do is a java program that calls an executable program with some given parameters in ubuntu. I've found the code above in another stackoverflow question:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
pb.command("bash", "-c", "./runCalculator.sh");
Process process = pb.start();
int retValue = process.waitFor();
```

But how can I cd to the executable file first and then execute the program, displaying its output, through java?
Thank you.

Comment: You could always specify the _absolute path_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

Use absolute path

```
pb.command("bash", "-c", "/path/to/runCalculator.sh");
```

Use `ProcessBuilder` directory method:

```
pb.directory(new File("/path/to"));
```

Comment: Thank you, I would Vote Up but I don't have the required level. I think I would choose the absolute path. Something else: If the output of the program is a text file, how can I keep the result in memory? Do I have to use 'BufferReader' to read the output file?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean whether the file is output to the display or not, perhaps better suited to a new question with more details to clarify

Comment: Yes you're correct, the output of the program is another text file saved on the program's folder, not to the display. I just though to clear this out without creating any new useless question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to `cd` anywhere, just specify the absolute path.

```
String path = "/home/Omen/runCalculator.sh";
pb.command("bash", "-c", path);
```

Comment: Thank you also. I would Vote Up too if I could!